# Accordion does not make page longer

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using an accordion like this:
[image]

The html looks like:

```
   <div id="cal-container">
        <div id="cal-side">
            <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
                <div class="accordion-group">
                    <div class="accordion-heading">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle project-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#project-list">Projects
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="project-list" class="accordion-body collapse">
                        <div class="accordion-inner">
                            <div class="event-container project-container">
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-group">
                    <div class="accordion-heading">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle task-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#task-list">Tasks
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="task-list" class="accordion-body collapse">
                        <div class="accordion-inner">
                            <div class="event-container task-container">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-group">
                    <div class="accordion-heading">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle case-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#case-list">Cases
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="case-list" class="accordion-body collapse">
                        <div class="accordion-inner">
                            <div class="event-container case-container">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="cal">
            <div id='calendar'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS looks like:

```
      .calendar
        {
            margin:16px;
            border-collapse:separate !important;
                -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
            border-radius: 7px;
            border-spacing:0;
        }

        .cal-container
        {
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            display: table;
            width:100%;
        }

    #cal-side
    {
        float:right;
        height:100%;
        width:200px;
        margin:50px 5px 5px 5px;
    }

    #cal-container
    {
        width:100%;
    }

    .top-link
    {
        display:inline-block;
    }

    .accordion-inner
    {
        padding:2px 2px !important;
    }

#cal{ 
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The problem is when I have too many events, The page does not ebd at the bottom of the content.

I suspect the style that causes it is:

```
  #cal{ 
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Without it it does scroll to the bottom, but then the calendar goes to the bottom too...

I need a way for it to look like my image, but the bottom of the page should be at the bottom. Events should not penetrate it.

I want a scrollbar for the items if they get bigger than the parent div / cal-side

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Try adding `overflow: hidden` to `#cal-side`. I'm guessing it's an uncleared float.

Comment: @Milo I would guess it was a float, but can you tell us what the applied CSS is?  You can use the developer tools in the browser of choice to see the applied CSS, that way we can actually see what is applied to the elements you are working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `height: auto` to the containing element.

Comment: What is the containing element?

Comment: It's hard to tell, try your developer tools. Can you post an example on http://jsfiddle.net? `height: auto` and `overflow: hidden` often fix issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set that accordion group to `overflow:auto` in order to cause scrollbars when necessary? I think that would appear more polished.

UPDATE

```
#case-list {
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Add a CSS style for either `#case-list` or `.case-container`, whichever is the block container for the accordion.

Comment: I can't help you further without seeing the generated code for the accordion. You probably have a containing element somewhere in your accordion that is `position`ed out of the document flow. You can try changing `#case-list` in my code to `#cal-side`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the above answers. Code is for illustration only.

```
  <div id="calendar">
    <div id="calside-back">
    </div>
    <div id="calside-front">
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#calendar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  position: relative;
}

#calside-back {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}

#calside-front {
  width: 40%;
  height: 150%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

The calside-front element is absolute so will overflow its parent element and the calside-back element will "reserve" the space in the parent so that the calendar will not be hidden behind calside-front.

If calside-front grows taller than the page then the page scrollbars will appear.

Demo [here](http://jsbin.com/azezob/1/edit)